# WPF UI overlay disable hit box and allow mouse to click thru?

Tags: c#, wpf

If I want to draw some UI element ex TEXT label on-top as a general overlay for windows but I don't want them to interact with the mouse, so its still possible to click on whatever button/application that's rendered underneath, how do I do that? **"IsHitTestVisible="False"** still blocks the mouse from the underlying applications.

```
WindowStyle="None"
ShowInTaskbar="False"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Background="Transparent"
```

Example can't click on the windows bellow when over the non transparent part of the WPF application.

[image]

Comment: @FCin as a test I have created a new VS project and only added a Large text label and set it all to transparent and "IsHitTestVisible="False" so should not be anything that captures the click event, the issue it block the mouse only where the text is.

Comment: @YvetteColomb have added an image now.

Comment: @YvetteColomb well no part of the WPF  is going to be clickable, its simple going to be a windows UI application drawing some text / bitmaps ontop of screen basically similar to "gdi+ draw to screen" .

Comment: Setting `e.Handled` to False in your View.Clicked event makes any difference?

Comment: @Vinicius not sure what you mean with "View.Clicked event" I don't have any click event added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution it was a bit more convoluted than I thought it would be also don't even have to set IsHitTestVisible="False".

**[Download working test VS project here:](http://www.patan77.com/download/clickThruUI.zip)**

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace clickThruUI
{

    public static class WindowsServices
    {
        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
        const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

        public static void SetWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            var extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            WindowsServices.SetWindowExTransparent(hwnd);
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```